# MySQL slower performance *with* indexes?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I'm writing an app that uses MySQL to save file hash data to a simple DB with a single table. I's created as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hash_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hash_db.main_tbl  
(                                       
  sha256       CHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY    ,
  sha1         CHAR(40) UNIQUE KEY     ,
  md5          CHAR(32) UNIQUE KEY     ,
  created      DATETIME                ,
  modified     DATETIME                ,
  size         BIGINT                  ,
  ext          VARCHAR(260)            ,
  path         TEXT(32768)             ,
  new_record   BOOL                     
 )                                      
ENGINE = MyISAM

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sha256_idx ON hash_db.main_tbl (sha256)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sha1_idx   ON hash_db.main_tbl (sha1)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX md5_idx    ON hash_db.main_tbl (md5)
```

Then I'm doing ***only*** simple selects and inserts of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM hash_db.main_tbl WHERE
      sha256 = '...'   OR
      sha1   = '...'   OR
      md5    = '...'


INSERT INTO hash_db.main_tbl
  (sha256, sha1, md5, created, modified, size, ext, path, new_record) VALUES
  (
    '...'                    ,
    '...'                    ,
    '...'                    ,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(...)       ,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(...)       ,
    ...                      ,
    '...'                    ,
    '...'                    ,
    TRUE                                  
  )
```

Data is pretty much random and uniqueness probability is very high (not that it should matter, or should it?).
First question, is it normal that InnoDB is much slower (~7x slower) than MyISAM for such usage? I read that it's supposed to be the other way round (tried with 512M innodb_buffer_pool_size, no difference).

Second... I have tested with and without indexes (MyISAM) and the version with indexes is actually slower. These are actual performance data as measured by my app (using performance counters in C):

```
With indexes:
Selects per second: 393.7
Inserts per second: 1056.1

Without indexes:
Selects per second: 585.3
Inserts per second: 1480.9
```

The data I'm getting is repeatable. I have tested with enlarged key_buffer_size (32M, default being 8M).

What am I doing wrong or missing?

================================================================================

Edited after Gordon Linoff's suggestion:

I have tried with UNION ALL and I get actually decreased performance, 70 selects per second precisely.
The output from EXPLAIN is as follows:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE md5 = '...'

+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main_tbl | const | md5           | md5  | 97      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+


EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE md5 = '...' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE sha1 = '...'

+----+--------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys         | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | main_tbl   | const | md5                   | md5  | 97      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | UNION        | main_tbl   | const | sha1,sha1_idx,md5_idx | sha1 | 121     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL   | NULL                  | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+-----------------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+


EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE md5 = '...' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE sha1 = '...' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM main_hash_db.main_tbl WHERE sha256 = '...'

+----+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type  | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | main_tbl     | const | md5                   | md5     | 97      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | UNION        | main_tbl     | const | sha1,sha1_idx,md5_idx | sha1    | 121     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  3 | UNION        | main_tbl     | const | PRIMARY,sha256_idx    | PRIMARY | 192     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3> | ALL   | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

Which made me see I had an error in the index creation (I was creating two separate indices for the 'sha1' column). But after the fix things are still slow (~70 selects per second), and here's the output for `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | main_tbl     | const | md5,md5_idx        | md5     | 97      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  2 | UNION        | main_tbl     | const | sha1,sha1_idx      | sha1    | 121     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
|  3 | UNION        | main_tbl     | const | PRIMARY,sha256_idx | PRIMARY | 192     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL            |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2,3> | ALL   | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |     NULL | Using temporary |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-----------------+
```

================================================================================

Third edit upon further discussion (see below). Here's the `EXPLAIN` output for the original query (no additional indexes defined, database is created as described above):

```
explain extended select path from main_hash_db.main_tbl where sha256 = '...' or md5 = '...' or sha1 = '...' ;

+----+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type        | possible_keys    | key              | key_len    | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | main_tbl | index_merge | PRIMARY,sha1,md5 | PRIMARY,md5,sha1 | 192,97,121 | NULL |    3 |   100.00 | Using union(PRIMARY,md5,sha1); Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------+------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Performance as measured by my app:

```
Selects per second: 500.6
Inserts per second: 1394.8
```

This is the result with 3 selects (issued separately, not with `UNION`):

```
Selects per second: 2525.1
Inserts per second: 1584.3
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you would expect `insert` without an index to be faster.  There is no mystery there.  The index does not have to be maintained.  In fact, when doing large inserts, a good strategy is often to drop the indexes first, do the inserts, and then rebuild them.

The `select` is more troublesome.  After all, that is where you want the indexes to be used.  Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM hash_db.main_tbl
WHERE sha256 = '...'   OR
      sha1   = '...'   OR
      md5    = '...';
```

This happens to be a worst case for index usage.  You would need to look at the `explain` to see how the indexes are being used.

My recommendation is to write the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM hash_db.main_tbl
WHERE sha256 = '...'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM hash_db.main_tbl
sha1   = '...'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM hash_db.main_tbl
WHERE md5    = '...';
```

(Or use `union` if you really want to eliminate duplicates.)

This should take advantage of each index for each subquery and should give you the performance you want.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it actually worsens performance by a lot, I'm getting 70 selects per second now. My guess is that the indexes are actually being used but a lot of disk accesses are occurring, instead of RAM cache ones. Am I on to something? Should I increase some buffers in my.ini? (which ones?)

Comment: You may need better buffers, but have you looked at the `explain` plans.

Comment: Gordon, I edited the original question with the `EXPLAIN` outputs.

Comment: @user3671607 . . . I don't see an `explain` for the `or` query.  If you are not using `or`, but have three separate queries for each hash, then the original formulation is best.

Comment: I added the `explain`s only for the `union all` queries because it's with these that the `select`s are the slowest (the magic 70/s number). I'm trying to undertand why. Key buffer hits are 100%. Oh, and upon further reading  it looks like `UNIQUE` keys are automatically creating B+tree indexes. Is this right and my indexes are superfluous?

Comment: And I'd still like to understand why adding the "extra" indexes slows `select`s down by a factor of almost 10.

Comment: @user3671607 . . . A `unique` constraint automatically creates an index, so an additional index is superfluous.

Comment: +1. I suspect Gordon's suggested SELECT is "slower" than the original because of the `TEXT` column. MySQL usually uses the Memory engine for temporary tables (up to smaller of `tmp_table_size` or `max_heap_table_size`)... but Memory engine does *not* support TEXT or BLOB columns, so MySQL uses the MyISAM engine instead. I suspect the original query was not "Using temporary", which is why that query is faster. (We'd really need to see the EXPLAIN output for the original query, with the `OR`'d equality predicates on different columns.)

Comment: Added `explain` output for the original query and performance data.

Answer (score 0):

you will decrease performance and slow the flow with your data base because you will create a wide number of Indexes

every time when insert one tuple that s mean  you will increase directly the number of Index in your System SGBD

when you do a selection it s like a research .. with a wide number of indexes make some challenge in the System ; like priority and you will have a wide number of  priorities you have 1000 tuples in your DB with 3000 indexes

every software have his methode to manage indexes ; and you must know how to master indexes then you can push the System in his maximum potential 
you can use for example trrigrs with indexes to make a good balance